# cannot reshape array of size 250670 into shape (7162,7,2)

Tags: deep-learning, lstm

`X_train=X_train.reshape((len(X_train), 7, 2))`

`X_test=X_test.reshape((len(X_test), 7, 2)`

ValueError:cannot reshape array of size 250670 into shape (7162,7,2)
how can we find required dimension value for reshaping?

Answer (score 0):

The new shape(7162 * 7 * 2 =100268) is not compatible with the original shape(250670).

> 250670 = 7162 * 7 * 5

So, you can try :

```
X_train=X_train.reshape((len(X_train), 7, 5))
```

Or you can set one of the dimention to -1 :

```
X_train=X_train.reshape((len(X_train), 7, -1)
```

it will give the same result as before.

Check the documentation [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) for more